# Is it possible to call WebAssembly functions from Go?

Tags: go, webassembly

I would like to compile a C++ library to webassembly and then use the webassembly library from a Go program. Is it possible? I'm aware of cgo but unfortunately I'm running the code in a restricted environment so I can't use cgo. WebAssembly seems to have a kind of interface for JavaScript so I assume any other language should be able to use the same interface.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what WebAssembly is. It has an interface to JavaScript because it is meant to work on web browsers, where JavaScript is the only native language available. Browsers run only JavaScript, so, in order to make WebAssembly work there, they needed to inferface with JavaScript as well. If you're not making a program that is supposed to work on web browser, you won't be using WebAssembly as well.

Comment: @paulotorrens I think you actually got it wrong. As far as I understood  webassembly is not designed to work on web browsers only. It actually targets IoT/embedded environments too. http://webassembly.org/docs/non-web/  . To quote the important bits: `WebAssembly could be used as a portable binary format on many platforms, bringing great benefits in portability, tooling and language-agnosticity`

Comment: Fair enough; but it's been designed for the web, and, even on the web environment, it's still a new technology. Also, the JavaScript interface is surely meant for the web, even if WebAssembly could be used elsewhere. As of now, it won't be so simple to interface to anything else. Do you *need* to interpret it? Because, if you're simply trying to use a C++ library in a Go program, there are certainly easier ways, since you can compile them together using your native compiler. Could you give more details of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I assume that just like JavaScript can access WASM modules any other language should be able to do so. How exactly does JS call wasm?  My use case is a Go applications that needs to execute/load WASM modules on demand just like JS does in a kind of 'plugin' architecture. The application is accessing the DOM (and thus discovers the wasm links)  through the webkit API. Simply said think that instead to use JS I use Go bindings to the webkit objective-C API ( https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.htmli)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the only implementations of WebAssembly that currently exist are the ones within JavaScript engines like V8. JavaScript may call and load WebAssembly because the same virtual machine implements both, and, by design, knows how to bridge them. So, if you want to embed WebAssembly in your Go program, you would need to either use a JavaScript engine or implement your own virtual machine to interpret WebAssembly (and thus add an interface to your Go code on it). WebKit uses JavaScriptCore as its virtual machine, which seems to support WebAssembly; you could use it.

Comment: If you have WA, you can interface to it in Go by either running a JS interpreter in Go, or by using [GopherJS](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs) to _also_ compile your Go to JS. Likely a better solution in your case is to use cgo to interface directly with the C++. I don't think WA gives you any advantage--it just adds another unnecessary (and possibly insurmountable) abstraction layer.

Comment: There are non-browser implementation of WebAssembly, e.g. https://github.com/AndrewScheidecker/WAVM, but AFAIK nobody has made it easy to call to / from Go. It's definitely possible, simply hasn't been done yet.

Answer (score 0):

Recently WebAssembly compilation support has landed for go.  So it should be possible to call other modules from go code that has been compiled to WebAssembly.

Comment: How can I do that?(obviously, without using javascript)